# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined main.jsx:17

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I am receiving the following error and have tried for hours to get rid of it without success:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined
>   main.jsx:17

The component which I named main.jsx has the following codes:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
//import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

//import Posts from './both/collections/post.js';
Main = React.createClass({
mixims:[ReactMeteorData],
getMeteorData(){
    let data = {};
    data.posts = [];
    data.ads = [];
    data.posts = Posts.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}}).fetch();
    data.ads = DBAds.find({},{}).fetch();
    return data;
},
render() {
    var adobj = {_id:1,text:'My First Ad',title:'Some Company' ,image:     'http://placehold.it/160x160'};
    var posts = this.data.posts.map(function(record){
        return <Post key={record._id} post={record}/>
    });
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-9 col-sm-11" id="main" >
        <div>
            <div className="full col-sm-9">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <Statusform/>
                            {posts}
                        <button className="btn btn-md">More</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                        <Ads ads={adobj}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )   
}
});
```

Pls I need help out of this error and chiefly to understand why I was having the error. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Odds are the subscription is not ready when the code runs so `this.data` is undefined

Comment: @MichelFloyd: `this.data` should be available at `render()` even when subscriptions aren't yet ready.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there. It's `mixins`, not `mixims`.

Comment: Thank you @aedm. You're a live saver. Thanks again.